# how to make a function that returns all the value from MultiDimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, server-side

I want to make a function in `php` which process the given array (of any dimension) and return all the value of that array. Here's my code so far:

```
    <?php  function resolve_array($args){     //To resolve 2 dimensional array

    foreach($args as $i => $i_val ){

        if(is_array($i_val)){
            foreach($i_val as $z=>$z_val ){
            echo  $z_val;
            }
         }else
        {
            echo  $i_val;
        }
         }}  ?>
```

this function resolves two dimensional arrays, i want to loop it to resolve the whole array.
I use this function to get the dimension of the array.

```
     <?php function countdim($array){ //To get the dimension of array
        if (is_array(reset($array)))
        {
            $return = countdim(reset($array)) + 1;
        }

        else
        {
            $return = 1;
        }

        return $return; }   ?>
```

I find myself lost in trying to display all the value, 
any idea how to go ahead? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by `resolve` ?

Comment: @vivek_23 i mean to get each and every value stored in that array

Comment: Why not simply use something like `var_export()`? Or `json_encode()`?

Comment: Array_walk_recursive http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Comment: @arkascha sorry i was not aware of those function i searched it on web but could not find anything thanks

Comment: @Andreas thanks i was not aware of those functions thanks :)

Comment: I suggest you start taking a look into the documentation. That should be your first source of information, actually: http://php.net/manual/en

Comment: @arkascha i will

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would want to do that.

Anyways, this code snippet collects all values in the multidimensional array into a separate array.

```
<?php        

$values = array();

$collection = array(
        array(
            61854,
            "sdkfjh",
            "ldsjf" => array(
                "25",
                "jsdbf" => array(
                    9874158,
                    array(),
                    array(
                            6
                        )
                )
            ),
        ),
        23,
        array(
            "abcyx",
            "hey",
            12546,
            "iii" => array(
                "odsfgv",
                521845
            )
        ),
        61874
    );

function resolve($collection,&$values){
    foreach($collection as $each_key => $each_value){
        if(is_array($each_value)){
            resolve($each_value,$values);
        }else{
            $values[] = $each_value;
        }
    }
}

resolve($collection,$values);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($values);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 61854
    [1] => sdkfjh
    [2] => 25
    [3] => 9874158
    [4] => 6
    [5] => 23
    [6] => abcyx
    [7] => hey
    [8] => 12546
    [9] => odsfgv
    [10] => 521845
    [11] => 61874
)
```

Comment: If only values is of importance, then yes this works. But as you demonstrated yourself it does not keep the associative key.

Comment: Agreed, but keeping keys could go a long way(because of nesting) making it multidimensional again.